# Copy File One folder to another folder in Google Drive using file list from text file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, copy

I have four folder
Main Folder,
Folder 1,
Folder 2,
Text Folder

I want to copy some file from `Main Folder` to `Folder 1` and `Folder 2`

there is two text file inside `Text Folder` lets say `Folder 1.txt` and `Folder 2.txt` screnshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re1zo.jpg each file contains filename which is available inside `Main Folder`. now i want script which will get the file list name from the `Folder 1.txt` and copy to `Folder 1` also file list name from the `Folder 2.txt` and copy to `Folder 2`

here is my current working code

```
function copyfile(obj) {
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(obj.sourceFolderName).next();
  var file = source_folder.getFilesByName(obj.filename);
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(obj.destinationFolderId);
    var srcFile = file.next();
    var newName = srcFile.getName();
    srcFile.makeCopy(newName, dest_folder);
  }
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  // Please set this object.
  var object = [
    {filename: "filenames_value1", sourceFolderName: "sourceFolderName_value1", destinationFolderId: "destinationFolderId _value1"},
    {filename: "filenames_value2", sourceFolderName: "sourceFolderName_value2", destinationFolderId: "destinationFolderId _value2"}
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    copyfile(object[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copying Files to Multiple Destinations**

```
function copyFiles() {
  var fA=[];
  var mainFolder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Main Folder').next();//assume one
  var textFolder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Text Folder').next();//assume one
  var files=textFolder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var filename=file.getName();
    if(filename.match(/Folder\d{1,}\.txt/)) {
      var desFldrName="Folder" + filename.slice(6,-4)
      var fnA=file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\n');
      for(var i=0;i<fnA.length;i++) {
        fA.push({name:fnA[i],srcFolderId:mainFolder.getId(),desFolderName:desFldrName});
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    var srcFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(fA[i].srcFolderId);
    var desFolder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(fA[i].desFolderName).next();//assume one
    var fi=srcFolder.getFilesByName(fA[i].name).next();//assume one
    fi.makeCopy(fi.getName(),desFolder);
  }
}
```

All Destination folders were empty before running script and the below images show the results of the copy.  Also shown the contents of the txt files which control the copy process.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. worked perfectly. actually you made the process much more easy way than i was thinking, thanks again :)

Comment: one small help please. in case if i like to get the main folder by id how can i do that? i tried `var mainFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('folder ID').next();` but got error `TypeError: Cannot find function next in object Main Folder. (line 3, file "Code")`

Comment: `var mainFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('folder ID');` getFoldersByName() returns a folderIterator() and getFolderById() returns a folder.  You can see that in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)